# How to see constraints IIS gurobi

Tags: python, python-3.x, gurobi

My model is infeasible, so I want to diagnose which contraints are the problem. I use the method ComputeIIS(), and tells me there are 19  constraints and 3 bounds, how can I see them?

> Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
> 0    2.9519740e+07   1.098984e+03   0.000000e+00      0s
>
> IIS computed: 19 constraints and 3 bounds IIS runtime: 0.00 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to write the ILP file after calling IIS. Alternately, you can iterate over variables and constraints, and check the [IISLB](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/iislb.html), [IISUB](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/iisub.html) and [IISConstr](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/iisconstr.html) attributes on the variable lower bounds, variable upper bounds and constraints, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_model.write('my_iis.ilp')
```

or

```
my_model.write('my_iis.lp')
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Your answer would be much more valuable to us if you added an explanation about what your code does and why it helps the OP